# Special character occurs during compilation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

During compilation of package some character is change into special(german) character. Like dm3 in to dmÂ³.
can anyone help me on this.?

Comment: Please add more detail about your problem - which package are you compiling

Comment: Explain more code or something.

Comment: maybe this error is due to Nls_lang ,

Comment: I created a package which contain 1 procedure it have dynamic query to insert & update into table.
During compilation of this procedure, it changes some character into special character. I do not have DBA privilege.

Comment: What is the character set of your DB? Use `SELECT * FROM v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';`

Comment: Hi  Wernfried,

SELECT * FROM v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';

its AL32UTF8

Answer (score 1):

Your string seems to be **dm³** (decimeter cubed)

It is alsways a nightmare when your SLQ*plus script contains non-ASCII charaters.

In your SQL script replace all `dm³` by `UNISTR('dm\00B3')`, then it should work. Maybe it also helps when you use an editor like TOAD or SQL-Developer instead of plain SQL*plus.

I found another solution. Before you start sqlplus set NLS-Environment according to current codepage.

```
C:\>chcp
Active code page: 850

C:\>set NLS_LANG=.WE8PC850

C:\>sqlplus user/pwd@db @(your script containing non-ASCII charaters)
```

It is even documented at Oracle: [NLS_LANG Settings in MS-DOS Mode and Batch Mode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b14312/gblsupp.htm#i634455)

Or you can do it the other way around, i.e set current codpage accoring NLS-Environment. Example:

```
C:\>REM for x64 Oracle Client

C:\>reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1 /v NLS_LANG

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1
    NLS_LANG    REG_SZ    AMERICAN_SWITZERLAND.AL32UTF8


C:\>REM for x86 Oracle Client

C:\>reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1 /v NLS_LANG

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1
    NLS_LANG    REG_SZ    AMERICAN_SWITZERLAND.AL32UTF8

C:\>

c:\>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

c:\>sqlplus user/pwd@db @(your script saved as UTF-8, without BOM)
```

See list of all available Codepage here: [Code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page)

On Unix/Linux the `chcp` equivalent is `locale charmap` or `echo $LANG`

Comment: Wernfried: Thanks for your suggestion.
But it was an example many other character are there which face same issue.